# why does this foreign key fail

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, heidisql

```
CREATE TABLE `fitness_pledges` (
    `ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `token` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `email_valid` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `entered_sweeps` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `referrals` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `email` (`email`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `token` (`token`)
)
COMMENT='holds validation token, first name, last name, email address, number of referrals and whether sweepstakes was entered\r\n'
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `finess_referrals` (
    `ID` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `token` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `referral_token` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `referral_validated` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    INDEX `token_FK` (`token`),
    INDEX `referral_token_FK` (`referral_token`),
    CONSTRAINT `referral_token_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`referral_token`) REFERENCES `fitness_pledges` (`token`) ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `token_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`token`) REFERENCES `fitness_pledges` (`token`) ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COMMENT='holds the first name, last name, email and validation token of the referrer as well as the token of the referred individual and a flag for whether the referred individual\'s email has been validated'
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

This Alter Table, generated by HeidiSQL, attempting to add a Foreign Key for the combined first_name, last_name and email fields fails with Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed. The fields are all defined the same, the collation is the same. Why is it failing?

```
ALTER TABLE `finess_referrals`
ADD CONSTRAINT `first_last_email_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) 
REFERENCES `fitness_pledges` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: Gordon, none of the fields in the attempted FK are INT nor BIGINT. All 3 are VARCHAR and the sizes match

Comment: The columns referenced in a foreign key have to be indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an index in the `fitness_pledges` table for `(first_name, last_name, email)` first. From [Using FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

It will create an index in the referencing table automatically if necessary, but it doesn't do so for the referenced table.

So you need to do:

```
CREATE INDEX first_last_email ON fitness_pledges (first_name, last_name, email);
```

Comment: @absolutely perfect boss +1

Comment: Thanks Barmar. Can't believe I forgot that! :(

Answer (score 0):

By the SQL standard, a foreign key must reference either the primary key or a unique key of the parent table. If the primary key has multiple columns, the foreign key must have the same number and order of columns

Comment: Thank you Hitesh, for confirming what Barmar siad